# How to pass multiple servers to an expect script?

Tags: scripting, expect

I'm trying to use an expect script to change my password on multiple servers, but I'm a little confused as to how to pass the list of servers through to it.

The script that I'm using is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# wrapper to make passwd(1) be non-interactive
# username is passed as 1st arg, passwd as 2nd

set username [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set serverid [lindex $argv 2]
set newpassword [lindex $argv 3]

spawn ssh -t $serverid passwd
expect "assword:"
sleep 3
send "$password\r"
expect "UNIX password:"
sleep 3
send "$password\r"
expect "password:"
sleep 3
send "$newpassword\r"
expect "password:"
sleep 3
send "$newpassword\r"
expect eof
```

And I'm trying to run it as such:

```
[blah@blah ~]$ ./setkey1 blah password 'cat serverlist' meh
```

which gives me the following output:

```
spawn ssh -t cat serverid passwd
ssh: cat serverid: Name or service not known
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "$password\r""
    (file "./setkey1" line 13)
```

So I then tried running the following for loop:

```
[blah@blah ~]$ for i in serverid; do `cat serverid`; ./setkey1 blah password $i meh; done
```

Which gave me the following:

```
-bash: staging01v: command not found
spawn ssh -t serverid passwd
ssh: serverid: Name or service not known
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "$password\r""
    (file "./setkey1" line 13)
```

If I try using the expect script, and just enter in one server name, it works as...um...expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this problem. I'd change the order of your arguments to be able to pass in multiple servers.

In the expect program:

```
foreach {username password newpassword} $argv break
set servers [lrange $argv 3 end]

foreach serverid $servers {
    # your existing code goes here
}
```

Then from the shell, invoke it like this

```
./setkey1 userid pass newpass $(cat servers.txt)
```

If you use bash, you can do

```
./setkey1 userid pass newpass $(<servers.txt)
```

Comment: Interesting. So, to be clear, I'm replacing:

    set username [lindex $argv 0]
    set password [lindex $argv 1]
    set serverid [lindex $argv 2]
    set newpassword [lindex $argv 3]

with 

    foreach {username password newpassword} $argv break
    set servers [lrange $argv 3 end]

    foreach serverid $servers {
    # your existing code goes here
    }

That looks like it makes a lot of sense.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Inside the `foreach` loop will be your spawn, expect and send statements.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar here is my way

```
set servers "server1 server2 server3"
set users "user1 user2 user3"
set passwords "password1 password2 password3"
set newpasswords "new1 new2 new3"

foreach server $servers user $users password $passwords newpassword $newpasswords 
{

Your commands using the variables server/user/password/newpassword

 }
```

this will run the commands in a loop for each element in the sets
so first server with first user with first password in a loop then goes to 2nd etc..